# MPEG DASH : Playing video segments from .m4s files instead of byte ranges in the MPD File using Simple DASH Player

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I have followed the tutorial from the link below to create an MPEG DASH player using HTML5 and javascript.
[Building a simple MPEG dash player using HTML5 and JS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn551368(v=vs.85))

In the given tutorial, it is possible to play the video segments using byte ranges. But for my application, I need the following features.

1. The video player should read the .m4s segment files and play the video instead of byte ranges.
2. The amount of data in the MediaSource buffer should be calculated periodically, also the amount of space left in the buffer.

Are these possible in the given player or Is there a better MPEG DASH Player with the above features?

PS: The MPD File is created using FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg  -f  avfoundation -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i 0 -vcodec libx264  -acodec aac  -b:v 800k  -f dash  -use_template 0  -min_seg_duration 4000 -single_file 1  -start_at_zero -live 1  ffmpeg.mpd
```

Also, I tried using the DASH.js player but the documentation is very vast in it. Can we get the size of the source buffer in dash.js (The space available in the source buffer and also the amount of space filled)? This is the main feature which is required for my project.

Edit : 
[Code which I tried](https://shrib.com/#streaming-1)

Comment: Did you try and see what happenes?

Comment: I wrote the code which is the question (Edited). Can you please check that out ?